# How to call Session ID from activity to Fragment in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

This is what I used in activity.

```
 val intent1 = Intent(baseContext, MenuFragment::class.java)
                        intent1.putExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", userEnteredEmail)
                        startActivity(intent1)
```

In Fragment I used,

```
val sessionId = intent1.getStringExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID")
```

In intent1 I got an error. it marked red color.

[image: error]

here the full code of fragment

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_menu.*

@Suppress("UNREACHABLE_CODE")
class MenuFragment : Fragment() {
    

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false)

        val sessionId = intent1.getStringExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID")
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            MenuFragment().apply {
                
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share your fragment complete code

Comment: You can't access intent in a fragment , To pass values in fragment you have to use setArgument()/getArgumnets()

Comment: Also you are creating your Fragment the wrong way , please see [how to create a fragment](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1364094-android-fragments-tutorial-an-introduction-with-kotlin)

Comment: @MilanPansuriya  I just added full code of fragment

Comment: @Nitish Can u tell me how to use Arguments in kotlin fragment. sry i'm new to kotlin

Comment: Try calling val sessionId = (context as Activity).intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID")

Comment: @Hascher it doesn't work for me

Comment: @ABI , I have written the answer on how to pass argument in kotlin

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to pass values to a `fragment` from `activity`.
Here I have created a new instance in a `fragment` in accessed it using a `companion object`. This way your `Activity` doesn't have to worry about bundle and all your data storing and retrieving is in one place

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Display the fragment in main activity and pass your data
        replaceFragment(FirstFragment.getInstance(yourName))
    }
}


// Extension function to replace fragment
fun AppCompatActivity.replaceFragment(fragment:Fragment){
    val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
    val transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.replace(R.id.host,fragment)
    transaction.addToBackStack(null)
    transaction.commit()
}
```

Fragment.kt

```
class FirstFragment : Fragment() {
     companion object {
 
        fun newInstance(name: String): TestOneFragment {
             val fragment = FirstFragment()
             // put values in the bundle
             val bundle = Bundle().apply {
                   putString("name", name)
             }
              // put bundle in the fragmnent 
             fragment.arguments = bundle

             return fragment
      }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)

        // Get the arguments from the caller fragment/activity
        val name = arguments?.getString("name")
       

        name?.let {
            textView.text = "\nName: $name"
        }
    
        return view
    }
}
```